# Unicode characters having asymmetric upper/lower case. Why?

Tags: unicode, uppercase, lowercase, symmetry, case-conversion

Why do the following three characters have not symmetric `toLower`, `toUpper` results

```
/**
  * Written in the Scala programming language, typed into the Scala REPL.
  * Results commented accordingly.
  */
/* Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S' (U+1E9E) */
'\u1e9e'.toHexString == "1e9e" // true
'\u1e9e'.toLower.toHexString == "df" // "df" == "df"
'\u1e9e'.toHexString == '\u1e9e'.toLower.toUpper.toHexString // "1e9e" != "df"
/* Unicode Character 'KELVIN SIGN' (U+212A) */
'\u212a'.toHexString == "212a" // "212a" == "212a"
'\u212a'.toLower.toHexString == "6b" // "6b" == "6b"
'\u212a'.toHexString == '\u212a'.toLower.toUpper.toHexString // "212a" != "4b"
/* Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE' (U+0130) */
'\u0130'.toHexString == "130" // "130" == "130"
'\u0130'.toLower.toHexString == "69" // "69" == "69"
'\u0130'.toHexString == '\u0130'.toLower.toUpper.toHexString // "130" != "49"
```

Comment: Perhaps because Unicode is ambiguous? Some glyphs have multiple representations in Unicode, and `toLower` after `toUpper` or vice versa normalizes to the "lowest" code points.

Comment: Jeff Moser's excellent [Turkey Test post](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) covered the Turkish I issue in particular.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the first one, there is [this explanation](http://www.siao2.com/2005/04/10/406880.aspx):

> In the German language, the Sharp S ("ß" or U+00df) is a lowercase letter, and it capitalizes to the letters "SS".

In other words, U+1E9E lower-cases to U+00DF, but the upper-case of U+00DF is not U+1E9E.

For the second one, U+212A (KELVIN SIGN) lower-cases to U+0068 (LATIN SMALL LETTER K). The upper-case of U+0068 is U+004B (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K). This one seems to make sense to me.

For the third case, U+0130 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE) is a Turkish/Azerbaijani character that lower-cases to U+0069 (LATIN SMALL LETTER I). I would imagine that if you were somehow in a Turkish/Azerbaijani locale you'd get the proper upper-case version of U+0069, but that might not necessarily be universal.

Characters need not necessarily have symmetric upper- and lower-case transformations.

**Edit:** To respond to PhiLho's comment below, the [Unicode 6.0 spec](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch15.pdf) has this to say about U+212A (KELVIN SIGN):

> Three letterlike symbols have been given canonical equivalence to regular letters: U+2126
> OHM SIGN, **U+212A KELVIN SIGN**, and U+212B ANGSTROM SIGN. In all three instances, the regular letter should be  used. If text is normalized according to Unicode Standard Annex #15, “Unicode Normalization Forms,” these three characters will be replaced by their regular equivalents.

In other words, you shouldn't really be using U+212A, you should be using U+004B (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K) instead, and if you normalize your Unicode text, U+212A should be replaced with U+004B.

Comment: I find wrong to give a lowercase equivalent of the Kelvin sign, the case of unit symbols should never be changed. Ie. even in all caps title, one should really write: "HE RAN 42 km IN 4 h"...

Comment: People are always confused about Unicode case, because they think everything works like the 26 ASCII letters, and it doesn’t. Think of the situation with the three Greek sigmas, for example. Also, there are lowercase code points that do not change case when mapped, etc. There are actually four kinds of Unicode case, in a sense, where "fold case" is the fourth. To compare two strings case insensitively, you must map each to their case folds and compare the results of that mapping.

Comment: Actually, it is not so much about Unicode as it is about cultural conventions. Germans uppercase sharp s as SS, Unicode only honors that practice.

Comment: @tchrist: Mapping to "fold case", how would you do it? Would `uc(lc(c))` do?

Comment: @maaartinus No amount of `uc` or `lc` combinations will reliably get you to the fold case mappings that Unicode provides. That’s why Perl provides an `fc` function. If you’re stuck in Java, you might look into the ICU libraries, which may have something.

Comment: @maaartinus Running `unichars 'uc(lc) ne fc && lc(uc) ne fc'` shows ***two round-trip exceptions*** in the Basic Multilingual Plane: `U+0131 ‭ı GC=Ll SC=Latin LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I` is one and
`U+1E9E ‭ẞ GC=Lu SC=Latin LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S` is the other.  The second is “new” and not likely to appear in many texts; it’s an uc character whose lc is `U+00DF ß LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP `, but the uc of that is in turn `SS`. The *“dotless i”* is a **big problem** in the Turkic languages, which need special casing rules it is so much of a trouble: `uc("ı")` is `I` but `lc("I")` is `i`.

Comment: @maaartinus All weird casing situations are in the BMP. There are 116 code points whose fc mapping differs from their lc mapping: 91 are Greek, 18 are Latin, 6 are Armenian, and 1 is `U+00B5 ‭µ GC=Ll SC=Common MICRO SIGN`. The 18 Latin exceptions (derived from running `unichars '\p{Latin}' 'lc ne fc'`) are: `U+00DF ß`,
`U+0149 ŉ`,
`U+017F ſ`,
`U+01F0 ǰ`,
`U+1E96 ẖ`,
`U+1E97 ẗ`,
`U+1E98 ẘ`,
`U+1E99 ẙ`,
`U+1E9A ẚ`,
`U+1E9B ẛ`,
`U+1E9E ẞ`,
`U+FB00 ﬀ`,
`U+FB01 ﬁ`,
`U+FB02 ﬂ`,
`U+FB03 ﬃ`,
`U+FB04 ﬄ`,
`U+FB05 ﬅ`, and
`U+FB06 ﬆ`. The last 7 of those are compatibility characters for old text only.

Comment: @tchrist: That's pretty crazy. It inspired me to [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135354/assuming-unicode-and-case-insensitivity-should-the-pattern-match-ffiss).

Comment: @maaartinus And me to an answer. Note that Java uses simple case folding in pattern matching, but full case mapping for its string functions.

Answer (score 3):

May I refer to another post about Unicode and upper and lower case..
It is a common mistake to think that signs for a language **have to be** available in upper and lower case!

[Unicode-correct title case in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360996/unicode-correct-title-case-in-java)

Comment: Particularly true for ideograms... :-)

Comment: You actually cannot do Unicode correct titlecase in Java.  There is only a `Character` method, not a `String` method the way is for uppercase and lowercase.  This is a real problem.