# Negative Lookbehind with \p{L} doesn't seem to work with ß and case insensitive flag

Tags: regex, ruby

Why am I not getting a match when I have the case insensitive flag *i* here?

**Regex Pattern:**

```
\(?<!\p{L})x\i
```

**Input:**

```
ß x
```

**Output:**
NO MATCH (WHY?)

---

**Regex Pattern:**

```
\(?<!\p{L})x\
```

**Input:**

```
ß x
```

**Output:**
MATCHES x

---

**Regex Pattern:**

```
\(?<!\p{L})x\i
```

**Input:**

```
ß  x
```

*(with two spaces)*

**Output:**
MATCHES x

Comment: Consider using slash `/` as delimiter.

Comment: Looks like it might have something to do with [Bug 13671](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13671#note-6) and [this issue](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/issues/92#issuecomment-373981492) especially since I can confirm the same using `"ﬆ e"`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135354/assuming-unicode-and-case-insensitivity-should-the-pattern-match-ffiss