# How to convert a character to Unicode title case, handling 1:M and not just converting to uppercase?

Tags: java, unicode, character, title-case

How do I convert a character into Unicode title case?

This seems like a simple question, but consider the following:

- Title case differs from upper case for some characters ([reference](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#4)).
- [`Character.toTitleCase(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toTitleCase(char)) only handles 1:1 mappings (e.g. doesn't work for characters like the German 'ß', which should map to 'SS').
- Java's `String` class only offers conversion to upper case (not title case).

Have I missed something in the core libraries that allow this transformation?

Comment: I've decided [the duplicate I previously chose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360996/unicode-correct-title-case-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) is more of a related question, than an exact duplicate. This question doesn't relate to locales, which is the main thrust of the other question.